# Error when using analytic function. I can not find the reason

Tags: sql, oracle, select, window-functions, analytic-functions

What is the mistake in this query?

```
    select department_id, first_name,
lag(first_name) over (partition by department_id order by salary rows between 1 preceding and 2 following), 
lead(first_name) over (partition by department_id order by salary rows between 1 preceding and 2 following) 
from employees order by department_id;
```

Error is:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

But parenthesis is ok. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

`lag()` and `lead()` do not accept a windowing clause (the `rows between` part). What they do is look at the "previous" and "next" row, so, if you think about it, a window frame just does not make sense from functional perspective.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) - emphasis mine:

> **Some** analytic functions allow the windowing_clause. In the listing of analytic functions at the end of this section, the functions that allow the windowing_clause are followed by an asterisk (*).

Further down in the documentation, `lag()` and `lead()` are listed without the asterisk (unlike, for example `avg()` or `count()`.

Presumably, you just want:

```
select 
    department_id, 
    first_name,
    lag(first_name)  over (partition by department_id order by salary) lag_first_name, 
    lead(first_name) over (partition by department_id order by salary) lead_first_name
from employees 
order by department_id;
```

---

Note that you can offset `lead()` and `lag()` by passing a second argument to the function (which defaults to `1` when not specified), like:

```
    lead(first_name, 3)  -- get the "third" following first name
        over (partition by department_id order by salary) lag_first_name
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need to select not the second first name, I need the third first_name after current first name. I cant to do this?

Comment: @LOP . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results and an explanation of what you want to do.  This answers the question that you asked here.

Comment: @LOP: you can pass a second argument to `lead()` and `lag()` - see my edit. For a more precise answer, you would indeed need to ask another question, as explained by Gordon Linoff.